# Android null value on EditText keylistener

Tags: android, null, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, onclicklistener

have now tried using this code but keep getting a null value when I hit enter? Can anyone suggest a solution to avoid this?

```
editext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {         
   public boolean onKey (View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {             
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub             
      if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {                  
         if ("test1".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {                    
            but4.performClick();                     
         }
      }                 
      else if ("test2".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {            
         but5.performClick();                 
      }              

      if ("test5".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {              
         but6.performClick();             
      }              

      if ("test7".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {              
         but7.performClick();             
      }             

      if (editext.getText().toString() != null){               
         testwrong.seText("wrong");               
      }          

      return true;             
   }
});
```

Comment: What does logcat say? It should give you the line where the exception occurred

Comment: check `anstext.getText().toString()` here `anstext` can b be null.

Comment: my mistake that wasn't in the original code though so have corrected but am still getting null value though, think it might be to do with return true causing the problem?

Comment: `return true` can not cause NPE :) check your all buttons `btn4,,btn5,btn6,btn7 and testwrong`

Comment: seems to trigger testwrong settext everytime I press enter, :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html), the `keyCode` value corresponds to the *hardware* key pressed. This probably does not refer to the soft keyboard.

Try to get the value of the keyboard key pressed from the `KeyEvent`.